# How validate on save supposed to work

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We are using EF 4.0 with code first approach. I have defined constraint for property length using attribute StringLength. I was under impression that SaveChanges for Context which tracks entity with data that is longer than specified constraint will throw validation exception.
But unfortunately it is not happen. If I do GetValidationErrors() before SaveChanges I see there expected error. Can someone shed some light how this stuff should work?

Update: Found where problem is. In order to track down entities which will be affected by SaveChanges we are using underlying ObjectContext of DBContext (through IObjectContextAdapter). SaveChanges has been invoked for ObjectContext, when I have switched to DBContext.SaveChanges issue has been resolved.

Comment: Did you set `dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false` somewhere? BTW: EF 4.0 does not have code-first. Can you check the version you are using, it must be between 4.1 and 4.3 (or EF 5.0 beta)?

Comment: Yes I am absolutely sure that ValidateOnSaveEnabled is true. We are using System.Data.Entity.dll with runtime version v4.0.30319 (version 4.0.0.0) and it includes both code first and GetValidationErrors and ValidateOnSaveEnabled.

Comment: You should also have a "EntityFramework.dll" referenced in your project. "System.Data.Entity.dll" does not include code-first. Code-First is an extension in the separate assembly "EntityFramework.dll" (which also contains an extension of the *namespace* "System.Data.Entity" though). The important thing to know is the version of the "EntityFramework.dll".

Comment: Ah, I just saw, that you already solved the problem, congrats! You can post it as an answer and accept your own answer. It may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found where problem is. In order to track down entities which will be affected by SaveChanges we are using underlying ObjectContext of DBContext (through IObjectContextAdapter). SaveChanges has been invoked for ObjectContext, when I have switched to DBContext.SaveChanges issue has been resolved.